# App is crashing on orientation change

Tags: android

App is crashing on orientation change,fragment has Fragmentstatepager

Crash log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException   
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.ja  va:569)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1281)
```

**Solution:** I fixed the bug by replacing getChildManager() with getSupportManager()

Comment: can you show code sample?

Comment: do u have appropriate layout in respective layout folder ?? have you added configChanges in manifest file ??

Answer (score 1):

Write following code in your Manifest file...

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

and write following code in YourActivity.java

```
    @Override

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

you can lock the orientation by adding the following code

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read and learn the official tutorial Android-Google about Layout.

For have a good showing, you have to add your elements (Button, TextView..) on multiple Layout.
After your App will be automatically resize depending orientation and size of your phone.

Or you can just locked orientation in your Manifest app

android:screenOrientation="landscape" or "portrait"

Good Luck.

EDIT :

Official :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

An other : 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-layout-basics--mobile-3671

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I hadn't thought. Thanks I will fix that.